# MySQL COUNT with and without a HAVING clause

Tags: mysql

I need to know the COUNT of a query, and also the same query with a HAVING clause

By way of illustration (not the real case, but illustrative), if table *pupilTable* contains a list of *pupil* and their *class*, and I want to know the number of classes, and also the number of classes with more than 25 children:

I know I can get the total number of classes using:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS NumAllClasses FROM pupilTable GROUP BY class
```

I know I can get the number of big classes with the condition using:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS NumBigClasses FROM pupilTable GROUP BY class HAVING COUNT(pupil) > 25
```

Is there a simple (single query) way of getting both at the same time?  Google has not been my friend :(

Edited to add illustrative data

Comment: I think that 2 queries are required.

Comment: It might be possible for this to be solved in one SELECT statement. However, try to give sample data and your expected output to confirm that.

Comment: Seven years on, this gets its first vote - a downvote - without any comment or an answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without any verification:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count1 FROM table WHERE condition UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count2 FROM table WHERE condition HAVING second-condition
```

But note that i guess the second label will get lost so you will have both count-nrs returned under the label count1

Comment: `UNION ALL` will be the solution.

Comment: @Antoniossss You are absolutly right, UNION would otherwise strip out the case where both querys return the same amount of rows counted.

Answer (score 0):

You can user the following query:

```
    select count(users.id) count1, count(u.id) count2 from users left join users u on users.id = u.id and u.fname = "abc" where users.id > 10
```

Here, I have used two conditions. You need to make relevant changes in this query to get desired output.

Here, user. and u. are the conditions.

In above query,

```
user.<condition1> : u.fname = "abc"
u.<condition2> : users.id > 10
```